# How to implement a simple generic comparison in C#

Tags: c#, generics, compare

I am just begining to explore the basic of using generics and would have thought i could implement this simple pattern to solve a typical problem in my daily use.  I have spent days searching for a simple example.  I can find examples for looking for .Equals, but not much past that.  I want to be able to instantiate with things like:

```
Spec<double> voltageSpec;
Spec<int> cyclesSpec;
Spec<myClass> fishInTheOceanSpec;
```

then be able to :

```
bool isGood = voltageSpec.inSpec(5.0);
bool isGood cyclesSpec.inSpec(2);
bool isGood fishInTheOceanSpec.( new myClass(20));
```

My attempt is shown below.

```
/// <summary>
///  Generic object to hold a specification i.e min and max limits.
///  Implements a method to determin if a value is between limits.
/// </summary>
public class Spec<T> : IComparer<T> 
{
    public Spec()
    {
        Min = default(T);
        Max = default(T);
    }
    public T Min { get; set; }
    public T Max { get; set; }
    public bool inSpec(T Value) 
    {
        if ((Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(Value, this.Max) <= 0) &
            (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(Value, this.Min) >= 0))
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x == y) return 0;
        if (x < y) return -1;
        if (x > y) return 1;
    }

    public Spec<T> Copy()
    {
        return (Spec<T>)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably ment && in Compare part of the class.

Comment: @EK, Consider using full words for class names, i.e. name range class Range instead of Spec (which is probably should include ranges for particular properties as members instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refactor as follows - make `T` be responsible to provide the comparison - this works already for primitive types, your custom classes just have to implement `IComparable<T>`:

```
public class Spec<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public Spec()
    {
        Min = default(T);
        Max = default(T);
    }
    public T Min { get; set; }
    public T Max { get; set; }
    public bool inSpec(T Value)
    {
        if(Value.CompareTo(this.Max) <=0 &&
            Value.CompareTo(this.Min) >=0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public Spec<T> Copy()
    {
        return (Spec<T>)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your class like this

```
public class Spec<T> : IComparer<T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    .... 
}
```

Then you can apply `CompareTo` to `T`

```
public int Compare(T x, T y)
{
    return x.CompareTo(y);
}
```

Basic types like `int`, `double` or `string` do implement `IComparable<T>`.